# ¿Cómo almacenar en un mismo array los datos arrojados de mi forEach() y no en array por dato en Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, array, vue.js, foreach

Todos los datos los quiero poder guardar en un mismo array, pero si lo intento se crea un array por dato.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La ventaja de usar forEach es la capacidad que tiene de iterar sobre objetos, pero si necesitas iterar sobre un array simple puedes usar filter:

```
created() {
    const miArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    this.nuevoArray = miArray.filter(item => item) // Aqui puedes agregar otras operaciones
},
data: {
    nuevoArray: [] //[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
}
```

si fuese un array de objetos lo podrias procesar con map de la misma manera

```
    created() {
    const miArray = [{nombre:'james', id:1}, {nombre: 'jane', id:2},{nombre: 'paul', id:3}];
    this.nuevoArray = miArray.map(item => item.id) // Aqui puedes agregar otras operaciones
},
data: {
    nuevoArray: [] // [1,2,3]
}
```

en ambos casos puedes usar comparaciones, evaluaciones u otras operaciones para obtener el resultado deseado.

Answer (score 0):

¿Algo así?.

```
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    created() {
        const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
        nums.forEach(num => this.aa.push(num * 2))
    },
    data: {
        aa: [] //[ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20 ]
    }
})
```

Te he [preparado una demo](https://repl.it/@juanwmedia/Vue-Sandbox).